# Replacing "|" with line break with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have imported an old blog to a new host which has caused the formatting on my blog titles to change and be off. I would like to replace the "|" symbol with a line break. Does anyone have javascript code to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.replace(/\|/g, '\n')`.

Comment: If I'm honest, this sounds like a band-aid approach. You wouldn't want to forevermore use JavaScript to alter your titles on-the-fly right? I would have scrubbed the data pre-import instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var text = "line1|line2|line3";
text = text.replace(/\|/g, '\n');

console.log(text); // prints: line1
                   //         line2
                   //         line3
```